# Is it possible to conditionally enable or disable filters/streams with user input?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, automation, encoding

I have a Bash script that runs FFmpeg on a given video file and - along with lots of other things - adds a PNG watermark to it using an overlay. I'd like to be able to only apply the watermark on some videos by enabling or disabling it via user input, but the only way I know of to do this is to conditionally branch two separate FFmpeg commands - one that adds a watermark and one that doesn't.

Here are the two commands for comparison.

**With watermark:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -i "outro.mp4" -loop 1 -i "../Watermark/watermark3.png" \     
-movflags +faststart \
-preset ultrafast \
-filter_complex \ 
"color=black:16x16:d=$total[base]; \
[0:v]scale=-2:'max(1080,ih)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=$fadeduration:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(($fadetime)/TB)[v1]; \
[2:v]lut=a=val*0.7,fade=in:st=5:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=$length1:d=2:alpha=1[v2]; \
[base][v0]scale2ref[base][v0]; \
[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
[tmp][v1]overlay,setsar=1[tmp2]; \
[v2][tmp2]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[wm_scaled][video]; \
[video][wm_scaled]overlay=W-w-50:50:format=auto:shortest=1[outv]; \
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=$fadeduration[outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -c:a libopus -crf 17 "$output"
```

**Without watermark:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -i "outro.mp4" -loop 1 -i "../Watermark/watermark3.png" \ 
-movflags +faststart \
-preset ultrafast \
-filter_complex \
"color=black:16x16:d=$total[base]; \
[0:v]scale=-2:'max(1080,ih)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=$fadeduration:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(($fadetime)/TB)[v1]; \
[base][v0]scale2ref[base][v0]; \
[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
[tmp][v1]overlay,setsar=1[tmp2]; \
[tmp2]setsar=1[outv]; \
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=$fadeduration[outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -c:a libopus -crf 17 "$output"
```

This isn't ideal because it would require me to maintain two different commands that are 90% identical, which violates the DRY principle and results in twice the maintenance. Not to mention I would also need another two permutations of the command every time I wanted to conditionally enable another feature in the same way, so it's not at all future-proof and very prone to becoming spaghetti code fast.

Is there anything in FFmpeg that would allow me to conditionally enable/disable a certain filter based on user input? If not, what's the best way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Added an example. I suppose since the watermark is a stream of its own (the line that starts with `2:v...`) what I'm really looking for is a way to enable or disable streams based on user input. So if the user answers a prompt with `Y`, the variable `enable_watermark` gets set to `y` and `ffmpeg` enables the stream based on it. Essentially I think I'm depending on the fact that FFmpeg has some way of passing variables through, as it otherwise seems that what I want will be too complicated to accomplish via scripting alone and without the redundancy.

Comment: Your commands that you've provided won't run - they're missing `-filter_complex` and the one without watermark references the nonexistent `v2` label

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The real issue here is the you can't just remove the line starting with `2:v .... [v2]` because there are *other* subsequent lines that reference the `v2` label. I don't see why this can't be solved with an if-else block - `FFmpeg`'s filters don't natively support conditionals like that as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @pigeonburger If it's true then I will say the OP misled me with clumsy code. As I said, I don't really know `ffmpeg`. I used `diff` on the two snippets and it told me the difference is just one removed line. Oh well, garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @pigeonburger Good catch, I don't know how the `filter_complex` got lost and the unreferenced stream error was something I only caught during testing. Still, the command is not that much different so I wouldn't say it was garbage. Fixed now anyway.

Comment: @HashimAziz "I wouldn't say it was garbage" – It was not, not literally. "Garbage in, garbage out" is a phrase, GIGO. Your code that didn't work led to my solution that couldn't work. This is [what GIGO means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). And to be clear: although GIGO usually refers to a computer processing data, in this case the entity that analyzed your flawed code and got to the flawed solution was my brain. :) I'm glad you managed to build a working solution on this foundation. Despite my unfamiliarity with `ffmpeg` I trust you it works. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On initial testing I thought this would be pretty complicated, but it turned out to be simpler than expected - it can be dealt with entirely in Bash, by wrapping each stream that *references* the conditional stream in a variable.

The real trouble - as [*pigeonburger*](https://superuser.com/users/1213878/pigeonburger) guessed - is in taking care of *all* the references to the stream, especially the final one that outputs the video: this stream's variable needs to have its content set conditionally, and in my case also involved using a "dummy" filter like `setsar=1` to avoid an empty stream error.

After that, the hardest part is making sure all the stream labels match in both conditions - if not, they'll need to be conditionally renamed just like with the final stream.

The below example asks the user whether they want to apply a watermark to the video: if anything other than `N` or `n` is entered, it applies the watermark by setting the necessary streams and then running the FFmpeg command with them.

```
read -p "Add watermark to video? [Y/n] " -n1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]; then
unset wmstream1
unset wmstream2
wmstream3="[tmp2]setsar=1[outv];"
else
wmstream1="[2:v]lut=a=val*0.7,fade=in:st=5:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=$length1:d=2:alpha=1[v2];"
wmstream2="[v2][tmp2]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[wm_scaled][video];"
wmstream3="[video][wm_scaled]overlay=W-w-50:50:format=auto:shortest=1[outv];"
fi
ffmpeg -y   -i "$1" -i "outro.mp4" -loop 1 -i "../Watermark/watermark3.png" \
-t 20 \
-movflags +faststart \
-preset ultrafast \
-filter_complex \
"color=black:16x16:d=$total[base]; \
[0:v]scale=-2:'max(1080,ih)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=$fadeduration:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(($fadetime)/TB)[v1]; \
$wmstream1 \
[base][v0]scale2ref[base][v0]; \
[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
[tmp][v1]overlay,setsar=1[tmp2]; \
$wmstream2 \
$wmstream3 \
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=$fadeduration[outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -c:a libopus -crf 17 "$output"
```

Although it's probably far from being as robust or succinct as a better Bash programmer than me can make it, it's definitely more succinct and more maintainable than the alternative of messing with two separate commands.